# Dokan filesystem always displays in Film Strip view

Tags: dokan

We have created a virtual filesystem driver using Dokan for Windows.  For some reason, whenever the device is mounted on Windows XP, it defaults the windows explorer view to "Film Strip" mode.  This is annoying, as there aren't even any media files.

Current options passed to Dokan are as follows:

```
dokanOptions->Options |= DOKAN_OPTION_REMOVABLE;
dokanOptions->Options |= DOKAN_OPTION_KEEP_ALIVE;
```

Is there any way we can default/force the view for folders under a particular drive letter or device to not show this option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a driver for an IBM mainframe file system. My driver added a desktop.ini to the list of files. That desktop.ini does not really exist on the mainframe medium. In my desktop.ini I added the following lines and that fixed the problem you mention.

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=W:\my_icon.ico,0
[ViewState]
Mode =
Vid =
FolderType = Generic
```

Just say desktop.ini exists and report the size of the string. Then in the ReadFile function, memcpy that data to Buffer and set ReadLength to the number of bytes copied. You have to use \r\n at the end of each line.

Comment: This is a good idea; unfortunately I can't test this out anymore, as that code base has been retired.  I'm going to mark this as the answer though, as it does seem technically sound.

Answer (score -1):

No, there's no way to control visual representation of the disk contents. Creating a "network" disk type with proper shell support changes Explorer behavior slightly, but Dokan doesn't support such disk type (our Callback File System does).

Comment: Could you go into a bit more detail on the underlying structure of how it's handled?  Also do you represent CBFS?  If so I do have questions. :)

Comment: @Michael We have a special redirector driver (and a helper DLL) which emulates a network disk. When Windows sees that the disk is a network one, it requests less information from that disk, than from the regular disk, thus lowering network load. For tech.support with CBFS you are welcome to use our helpdesk ( http://www.eldos.com/helpdesk/ ), where our developers can give you detailed information and offer assistance.